# what is a request object in python socketserver api

Tags: python, sockets, request, xml-rpc

In python socketserver api, as well as xmlrpcserver, there are mentioned many times the request object,for example：

```
SimpleXMLRPCServer.process_request(self, request, client_address):
```

But I cannot find any description to this request object. What is it ? where in the python doc can I find the the expaination(it's attribute,method,etc) of the request object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the source (of [SocketServer.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/SocketServer.py?view=markup) in this case) to answer such questions. process_request is called in _handle_request_noblock, which gets the request from get_request. What that does depends on the SocketServer subclass. For a TCPServer, you'll find that it is the result of the socket accept() call.

Comment: Why does not the official python doc give some explaination on it ? Is it a result of the socket accept() call, not some kind of conn.recv(1024) ? What is it's type ? a string ?

Comment: It's documented in http://docs.python.org/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseServer.get_request

Comment: Thanks Martin, so do you mean that,according to the document section you pointed out, the request is a 2-tuple object ?